# Encoding a vCard as QR/Barcode for Apple Wallet

Tags: ios, barcode, vcf-vcard, passkit, apple-wallet

I am trying to use a *vCard* as the content of a QR or barcode in Apple Wallet. I've been able to encode the content, but the QR code is not readable - and I believe thats because I've not been able to prep/format the data ahead of time properly.

While I am using PHP, this isn't a language-specific question.

Here is a sample vCard that I've been using:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
REV:2023-11-08T00:00:00Z
N:Murphy;Jill;;;
ORG:Company
TITLE:Developer
EMAIL;INTERNET;WORK:test@example.com
URL:https://example.com
END:VCARD
```

In Apple's Wallet [format](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html), the [barcode data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/pass/barcodes) is specified in JSON format:

```
"barcode": {
    "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
    "message": "VCARD_DATA_HERE",
    "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1"
},
```

I've tried the following in various combinations:

1. Passing in the vCard text directly
2. Concatenate the vCard data into one line with "`\n`" delimiters
3. Using `urlencode` (PHP)
4. All of the above with Apple's various supported barcode formats

Those formats are:
PKBarcodeFormatQR, PKBarcodeFormatPDF417, PKBarcodeFormatAztec, and PKBarcodeFormatCode128

I know I can host a *vCard* and just have the barcode be of a URL but I am intentionally going for a self-contained version.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to format the *vCard* text before I put it into `pass.json` so it allows for a readable barcode?

Comment: This is just a random post I came across: https://ensourced.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/generate-addressbook-type-qr-codes/.  It shows a different syntax than you are using.

Comment: Thanks @MarkWarren - that appears to utilize Google's chart API to generate the code for a vCard, but thats not an option for me. I need to use Apple's method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further trial and error I stumbled upon the answer. It was in how the data is prepared. I had been concatenating each line of the *vCard* with the wrong delimiters.

I should have been using "`\n\r`", and in my case, once escaped would be "`\\r\\n`".

```
function getVCard($pass_name) {
    $vcard = '';
    $vcfFilePath = "./passes/$pass_name/vcard.vcf";
    if (file_exists($vcfFilePath)) {
        $vcard = '';
        $file = fopen($vcfFilePath, 'r');
        $vcard = '';
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $line = fgets($file);
            $vcard .= trim($line) . "\\r\\n";
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
    return $vcard;
}
```

In my `pass.json` for Apple Wallet, the relevant JSON snippet looks like this:

```
"barcode": {
    "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
    "message": "BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:3.0\r\nREV:2023-11-08T00:00:00Z\r\nN:Murphy;Jill;;;\r\nORG:Company\r\nTITLE:Developer\r\nEMAIL;INTERNET;WORK:test@example.com\r\nURL:https://example.com\r\nEND:VCARD\r\n\r\n",
    "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1"
},
```